# I can't manage to get my background video to show up on my react homepage

Tags: html, reactjs, video

I am trying to create a hero for the homepage of my react project that autoplays an mp4 - I have no errors in the console but still no video.

I triple checked the file path and the video plays fine when I go into my assets folder and yet nothing.

Any help would be much appreciated

import React from 'react';
import '../../App.css'

const style = {
heroStyle : {
display: 'flex',
justifyContent: 'center',
width: '100%',
height: '100%'
},

```
containerStyle: {
    position: 'absolute',
    top: '0',
    right: '0',
    bottom: '0',
    left:'0',
    overflow: 'hidden',
    width: '100%',
    height: '100%',
    backgroundSize: 'cover',
    backgroundRepeat: 'no-repeat',
    backgroundPosition: 'center', 
},
```

}

function Home() {
return (

```
<div className="hero" style={style.heroStyle}>
  <div className="video-container" style={style.containerStyle}>
    <video width="100%" loop autoplay muted>
    <source src="../../assets/video/Timeline1.mp4" type="video/mp4"/>
    <source src="../../assets/video/TimeLine1.mp4" type="video/webm"/>
    </video>
    </div>
</div>
```

);
}

export default Home;

Answer (score 0):

don't use relative path in the video source but instead use variables. take a look at the following code.

```js
import video from '../../assets/video/Timeline1.mp4';



export default function App(){

return(

<div className="hero" style={style.heroStyle}>
  <div className="video-container" style={style.containerStyle}>
    <video width="100%" loop autoplay muted>
    <source src={video} type="video/mp4"/>
    <source src={video} type="video/webm"/>
    </video>
    </div>
</div>
)


}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.2.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.2.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```